# converting NSArray to RLMArray with RKValueTransFormer fails converting outputValue to AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>

Tags: swift, restkit, restkit-0.20, realm

I am using RestKit and realm.io together.  I have an array of values (the array is url strings of pictures) being returned in JSON that should become a `RLMArray` of `RLMObject`s.  I believe the mappings are set up correctly because it makes an attempt to convert the results to an `RLMArray`.  But I get the following error from RestKit:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:449 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'picList' to representation of type 'RLMArray': Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 "Failed transformation of value '(
"Picture {\n\turl = ;\n\tremote_url = http://placekitten.com/g/500/500;\n}",
"Picture {\n\turl = ;\n\tremote_url = http://placekitten.com/g/400/400;\n}",
"Picture {\n\turl = ;\n\tremote_url = http://placekitten.com/g/300/300;\n}"
)' to RLMArray: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful."
```

So I created a value transformer to perform the transformation manually.  Here is my code:

```
func setupValueTransformerForPicList(){

    println("called value transformer function")
    var picListValueTransformer = RKBlockValueTransformer(validationBlock: { (inputClass:AnyClass!,outputClass:AnyClass!) -> Bool in

        if (inputClass.className() == "Array" || inputClass.className() == "__NSArrayM") && outputClass.className() == "RLMArray" {
            return true
        }
        return false

        }) { (inputValue:AnyObject!, var outputValue, outputClass, error) -> Bool in

            println("called value transformer")
            if let thisArray:NSArray = inputValue as? NSArray{
                var picRlmArray:RLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: Picture.className())
                for item in thisArray {
                    if let thisPicture:Picture = item as? Picture{
                        picRlmArray.addObject(thisPicture)
                    } else {
                        return false

                    }
                }
                outputValue = picRlmArray // this is the line that throws the error
                return true
            }
            return false
    }
    RKValueTransformer.defaultValueTransformer().addValueTransformer(picListValueTransformer)
}
```

However, I get the error message:

```
'RLMArray' is not convertible to 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>'
```

I've tried downcasting

```
 outputValue = picRlmArray as AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>
```

with the same result.  I've tried doing whatever this is (if it's even a thing)

```
outputValue = picRlmArray as AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<RLMArray?>
```

and get the error

```
'RLMArray' is not identical to 'AnyObject'
```

I'm a little out of my depth here, but feel like this should definitely be achievable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I'm also unable to return a swift array from this function.  It gives the same error.  I think this might be a more general question about how to return types that aren't `AnyObject`s.

Comment: Don't use `className()`, check the class type (`isKindOfClass`). Is your code being called? And I haven't been writing any swift, but should be parameter be `inout` instead of `var`?

Comment: Thanks wain.  But I think that isKindOfClass is a method for objects, not classes and inputClass and outputClass are of type `AnyClass`.  When I try to use inout I get a type mismatch.  And yes, the code is getting called.

Comment: Fair point, `isSubclassOfClass` is the appropriate method to use. I guess it's a swift casting issue but I can't offer much advice on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the current maintainer of RestKit, and I'm sad to say that I haven't had much of a chance to play around with using RestKit and Realm together, especially not with Swift.

I'll take a look at what might be causing this error.

EDIT:

It seems to me that doing `outputValue.memory = picRlmArray` instead of `outputValue = picRlmArray` would do the trick!

Comment: Thanks so much @segiddins.  I'm thinking this isn't necessarily a Realm issue as much as an issue of what type of value can be returned from a value transformer and how those values are cast with swift.  For instance, like I had mentioned in the edit, I'm also unable to return a simple swift array.  I'm new to iOS programming, though, and perhaps there is something I don't know about AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointers.  In any case I very much appreciate you looking into this.  -Mike

Comment: No worries! My guess is that the issue is really just assigning an object to an indirect pointer in general.

Comment: @MikeWrather I just edited my answer, please let me know if that solution works for you!

Comment: whatever you get paid isn't enough.  Can you give some insight into how this solution works?  Thanks!!

Comment: `outputValue` is an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`, and what you need to do is set the actual `memory` that that pointer points to.

Comment: Wondering what your impressions are with mixing together Restkit and Realm @MikeWrather, can you share your thoughts?

Comment: Hey @Andrespch - Both Realm and Restkit are amazing frameworks.  Restkit has a lot of features that make it great to use with CoreData, but I've managed to make it fit my needs with Realm.  However, you can see from the question I asked that there is some manual heavy lifting necessary to get them to play together.  I'm not expert with either framework, so there are probably more elegant solutions than the ones I've worked out. Do you have any specific questions regarding interoperability?

Comment: @Andrespch - also, judging by the fact that segiddins is wearing a Realm tshirt in his new photo and maintains restkit, he's likely the one you want to ask this question of.

Comment: hahaha yeah probably @MikeWrather. I'm just asking because I'm starting to use them together for a relative big project, so I was just wondering if you might advice against it after having used both frameworks together for a while, I think one cool new feature for RestKit would be automatic mapping of JSON arrays into RLMArrays, maybe I'll end up trying to build an RKValueTransformer class that does this, if I do and it the outcome is good I'll come back to share it.

Comment: @Andrespch - yeah, that's pretty much what the value transformer above does.  The project I built was big as well and it was my first time using either technology (and Swift for that matter).  Not pain free, but what is?