# AFNetworking with SSL Certificate

Tags: ios, swift, http, ssl, https

Project Setup :- 
Minimum iOS Version - 8.0

As Apple announced in WWDC 2016 that later this year (January 2017) all application must support Application Transport Security which was previously Bypassed by adding keys in the info.plist.

Now according to the documentation that states Application Transport Security is being introduced in the iOS 9 and macOS 10.11 using TLSv1.2

Link :-  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html

My Application is working on HTTP.

Going through the following links how to achive this :-

```
 1. http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258330/afnetworking-problems-with-tls-verification-of-a-self-signed-server-root-ca
 3. https://fastchicken.co.nz/2016/03/21/increasing-your-trust-certificate-pinning-on-ios/
```

After this i have couple of Questions :-

```
  1. Using TLSv1.2 with iOS 8, What would be the impact?
  2. Using SelfSigned Certi or third party certi would be benifited ?
```

Any Help would be Appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly validation of the SSL Certificate is one of the basic approaches that could be provided by the developer to provide secure connection between application and server.

Nice statements to read [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet).

1)Usage of the Transport Layer Security in the application with iOS 8 will enchant you're app with secure connection between application and server.
This could be reached by providing of the [SSL pinning](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning).

2)Self-signed certificate:

> In cryptography and computer security, a self-signed certificate is an
>   identity certificate that is signed by the same entity whose identity
>   it certifies.

As possible to conclude you going to signed certificate by you're self.The main disadvantage is in possibility of the [Man-in-the-middle attack](http://www.veracode.com/security/man-middle-attack) because of the Self-signed certificates cannot be revoked.

If the aim is to provide secure connection try not to use some third parties I think you understand why.

My way is usage of the SSL pining and [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org)

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg! Can multiple certificates can be used ??